# Android ActionBar/Toolbar colors different in Light vs Dark themes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I am trying to understand why the `ActionBar` is styled differently in Light vs Dark themes. Below is a simple settings screen that can toggle between Light and Dark themes with identical themes.

[image]

values\themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Dark application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SettingsApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-night\themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Dark application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SettingsApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values\colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue_normal">#FF3F7FBF</color>
    <color name="blue_dark">#FF2F6090</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
</resources>
```

In the Light them, the `ActionBar` comes across as blue and white, indicating it is using `colorPrimary` and `colorOnPrimary`. In the Dark theme it comes across as red and green, indiciating it is using `colorSurface` and `colorOnSurface`. Why are these applied differently and how can I get consistent application of colors on the `ActionBar`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908518/actionbar-background-style-not-changing-in-dark-theme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are these applied differently

**Quote from the documentation:**

> large surfaces should not use bright background colors because they can emit too much brightness. When applicable, the Material themes will provide this behavior out-of-the-box, e.g., by having the Light theme default to `Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Primary` and the Dark theme default to `Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Surface`.

So, though you have the same colors for both light & dark themes, but the `Primary` colors are the preferable colors in the light mode, and the `surface` colors are for the dark mode.

> how can I get consistent application of colors on the ActionBar?

This can be concluded from the previous documentation ..

So, you just need to, have `values\themes.xml` to contain:

1. `colorPrimary` & `colorSurface` to have the same value
2. `colorOnPrimary` & `colorOnSurface` to have the same value

Applying this to your example

**values\themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Dark application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SettingsApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For more info, please [check documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark).

Comment: The quote regarding Primary vs Surface suddenly makes everything clear. Thank you for the link and the XML sample (and for helping me yet again).

Comment: thanks. it wasted a day that I found out how to change toolbar color in dark mode.  I believe that android documentation website is worst. Stackoverflow users and medium have much better answers and content.