# Actionbar background style not changing in dark theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-dark-theme

Creating the [first app](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-first-template-project), I changed the actionbar's background to teal.

The problem is that it worked on light theme but not on dark theme.

Tested on both pixel 3 XL emulator and 2 different samsung devices.

How to custom an app's actionbar title for dark theme devices?

Working light theme (`.../res/values/themes.xml`): (See screencap below)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.HappyBirthday" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Not Working dark theme (`.../res/values-night/themes.xml`): (See screencap below)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.HappyBirthday" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Working Light theme Screencap:

[image]

Not working dark theme screencap:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673078/android-actionbar-toolbar-colors-different-in-light-vs-dark-themes/65674607#65674607

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "colorSurface" and "colorOnSurface" on your theme to change actionbar color in dark mode.
For example:

```
<item name="colorSurface">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorOnSurface">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
```

A similar problem is raised in the thread:
[Android ActionBar/Toolbar colors different in Light vs Dark themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673078/android-actionbar-toolbar-colors-different-in-light-vs-dark-themes)